# Excel VBA - Concatenate variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following variable in my Macro:

```
todaydate = Year(Date) + Month(Date) + Day(Date)
```

How do I make the value of `todayDate` to be `20150415` instead of `2034`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate it as string, you need to use `&`.
Like this:

```
todaydate = Year(Date) & Month(Date) & Day(Date)
```

But this will yield: `2015415`
To get what you want, try this:

```
todaydate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
```

which will yield: `20150415`

Comment: Thanks! That works! But I still want to learn how to concatenate variables in Macro. For example, now I would like to rename my active sheet based on a fixed string and the above todayData parameter.

ActiveSheet.Name = PO_ + todayDate

My expectation is the returned value should be "PO_20150415"

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:= "PO_" & Format(Now(),"yyyymmdd")
```

Hope this will help.